# How can I edit a QListWidget item without removing it to edit and adding back?

Tags: python, pyqt, qlistwidget

I would like to edit listWidget items that are selected via a button programmatically.  I am not entirely sure if there is a way to edit  selected items without having to remove the original items and add the new edit back in.

I saw this... but I am not sure this is what I need, as I can't pass in a new value:

```
selItems = listWidget.selectedItems()

for item in selItems:
    listWidget.editItem(item, "test")

TypeError: QListWidget.editItem(QListWidgetItem): too many arguments
```

Comment: When you say "edit", do you want the user to be able to type something?  Or do you want to change it programmatically?

Comment: Change it programatically myself

Comment: It is hard to answer without more details about what exactly you want. ARe you just trying to set the text of an item and initialize it? A minimal working example, describing what you expect to happen, would be really helpful here! (See this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Where is this "button" you want to press? QListWidgets are already editible via double clicking, it sounds like you are trying to do too much. Do you have a working QListWidget yet, a very simple one that you can post?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `editItem` method is used when you want the user to edit the item.  If the item is editable, by default, it will create a `QLineEdit` widget in the cell for the user to edit the text, unless you've created a `QItemDelegate` to create a different widget for editing.

To change the text of an item, just use `setText()`.  You can use `text()` to get the current text of the item.

```
sel_items = listWidget.selectedItems()

for item in sel_items:
    item.setText(item.text() + ' plus more text')
```

Comment: What about example if i dont want SelectedItems but i want to choose Item by index for example? i did not find any method for that.

Comment: @ErikŠťastný You mean like this? [`QListWidget.item(row)`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlistwidget.html#item)

Comment: Yep but please check link below. I have got some problems when using `.QListWidget.item(row) ` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41182466/python-pyqt-edit-item-at-specific-row-in-qlistwidget-without-takeitem-and-in